# How to generate a block diagonal data matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, matplotlib

The first synthetic dataset we used is a 100×100 matrix with four 25 × 25 block matrices diagonally arranged. The data within each block denotes the affinity of two corresponding points in one cluster, while the data outside all blocks denotes noise. The affinity data within each block are randomly
generated in the range of 0 and 1, while the noise data is randomly generated in the range of 0 and c, where c is set as 0.6, 0.7, and 0.8 respectively. Moreover, to make this clustering task more challenging, we randomly pick out 25 noise data points and set their values to be 1.

The wanted figure looks like this one with a color bar.
[image: The wanted figure looks like this one with a color bar]

Comment: What is the question? Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Show the data, your effort, and what kind of problem you have in picturing your data. Consider [reprex]

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` or `scikit-learn` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started on generating the matrix.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

c_min, c_span = 0.0, 0.7
x = c_min + c_span*np.random.random((100,100))
for i in range(4):
    j = i*25
    x[j:j+25, j:j+25] = np.random.random((25,25))

plt.imshow(x, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Overall, it sounds like you're asking for three different matrices, each with a different background range (0, .6), (0, .7), (0, .8).  If that's case, just change `c_span`.  (Also, it looks like you're using the 'jet' colormap, but that's not a good perceptual colormap, but if you want it you can use `cmap=plt.cm.jet` in the plot call.)